# VBA paste to visible cells only

Tags: vba, excel

I have range of cells on Sheet2 `F2:F41`, which I want to paste into visible cells in Sheet1. Visible cells on Sheet1 are in Range `M111:M643`. My Problem is, Excel pastes it to another cells as I want.

Snippet for it:

Do I miss loop or something like this?

```
Sheets("Tabelle2").Select 
Dim tgt As Worksheet
Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1") 
Dim from As Range 
Dim destination As Range 
Set from = Sheets("Tabelle2").Range("F2:F41") Selection.Copy   
Set destination = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("M11:M643").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) from.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("M111")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the internet - I forget where (could have been stackoverflow) - but it should do what you are looking for.  You may want to edit out the plethora of messages, I find them helpful to ensure I'm copying pasting the ranges I intended.

```
Public Sub Copy_Paste_Visible_Cells()
'This subroutine only handles copying visible cells in a SINGLE COLUMN

Dim RangeCopy As Range
Dim RangeDest As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim dstRow As Long

Set RangeCopy = Application.InputBox("Select a range to copy ", "Obtain     Range Object", Type:=8)
    MsgBox "The range you selected to copy is " & RangeCopy.Address

Set RangeDest = Application.InputBox("Select range to paste onto ", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)
    MsgBox "The range you have selected to paste onto is " & RangeDest.Address

If RangeCopy.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    If RangeDest.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        If RangeCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count <> RangeDest.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count Then
            MsgBox "Data could not be copied"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End If

If RangeCopy.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    'Copying a single cell to one or more destination cells
    For Each rng1 In RangeDest
        If rng1.EntireRow.RowHeight > 0 Then
            RangeCopy.Copy rng1
        End If
    Next
Else
    'Copying a range of cells to a destination range
    dstRow = 1
    For Each rng1 In RangeCopy.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Do While RangeDest(dstRow).EntireRow.RowHeight = 0
            dstRow = dstRow + 1
        Loop
        rng1.Copy RangeDest(dstRow)
        dstRow = dstRow + 1
    Next
End If

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code.

```
Sub copythis(ByRef rFrom As Range, ByRef rTo As Range)
    Dim rVisible As Range
    Set rVisible = rFrom.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rVisible.Copy destination:=rTo
End Sub
```

that should be called like:

```
Sub caller()
    copythis "range with hidden to be copied", "range to receive"
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't do what OP is asking for. This copies visible cells not pastes into visible cells

Comment: I badly misunderstood the OP. Apologies.